# Windows PowerShell "UnathorizedAccessException"

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10

I'm trying to run the command:

```
PS C:\Users\andre> New-Item -Path C:\Users\andre -Type File
```

But it keeps returning the following error:

```
New-Item : Access to path 'C:\Users\andre' denied
line:1 char:1
+ New-Item -Path C:\Users\andre -Type File
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo :          PermissionDenied: (C:\Users\andre:String) [New-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NewItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

I've added `powershell.exe` to Windows Defender whitelist beside running PowerShell as administrator, but nothing changes.
Is this a kind of account-related problem? Mine is the only existing account on the pc anyway. How could I solve this?

Comment: Presumably, you already have a folder called 'andre' in that location for your user profile.  What happens if you try to create a file with a different name?  For example:

    New-Item -Path C:\Users\andre2 -Type File

Comment: You are in the folder `c:\users\andre`, you can't overwrite it with a file called `c:\users\andre`. `New-Item` needs a path to somewhere that does not exist, or a path that exists and a `-name` for the new item's name.

Comment: As others have already mentioned you can't replace an existing directory with a file of the same name. Trying to do so will result in an access violation, as you observed. Why are you attempting to do this in the first place? What do you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

```
PS C:\Users\andre> New-Item -Path C:\Users\andre\text.txt -Type File
```

You have to complete the path with the filename and type